# AngularJS + TypeScript: this always null in filter function

Tags: angularjs, filter, typescript

I am just starting with Angular, and this problem has already been bugging me for hours:

Initially, I wrote a small test application in Javascript only. Now I wanted to switch to TypeScript, which basically works all fine. Except one thing: I created a custom timerange filter, which I just cannot get to work in the Typescript version of my app.

index.html:

```
<div ng-controller "MyController as ctrl">
    <input id="date_from_filter" ng-model="ctrl.dateFromFilter" />
    <input id="date_to_filter" ng-model="ctrl.dateToFilter" />


    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="event in ctrl.events | filter:ctrl.rangeFilter">
            <td>{{event.id}}</td>
            <td>{{event.timestamp}}</td>
            <td>{{event.value}}</td>
        </tr>
</div>
```

controller.js

```
class MyController {
    dateFromFilter: string;
    dateToFilter: string;

    constructor(public helperService: app.services.HelperService) { }

    rangeFilter(event) {
        // Compare mechanism, accessing this.dateFromFilter and this.dateToFilter and using helperService
        // But: `this` is always null in here
    }
}
```

Can anyone give me a hint on how I can do this? I think I got that this cannot be accessed as the scope is different inside the `rangeFilter` method. But what are my options?

Thank you!

UPDATE:

I am thrown a `TypeError: Unable to get property 'dateFromFilter' of undefined or null reference` (*.js:30:33)

Here is the compiled Javascript:

```
MyController.prototype.rangeFilter = function (event) {
    var x = new Date(this.dateFromFilter);
    //... more stuff..
}
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I have the same issue.

Comment: Sorry, no, I've never been. If I remember correctly we ended up with a completely different style of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the below code in my current angular TS project and it seems to work fine, if you have any questions, drop me a comment. If you need further info on what your `rangeFilter()` function is doing, put a `debugger;` on the first line of your `rangeFilter()` function.

```
class MyController {
    public dateFromFilter: string;
    public dateToFilter: string;

    public static $inject: string[] = ["$scope"];

    constructor(public $scope: ng.IScope, public helperService: app.services.HelperService) {}

    public rangeFilter(event) {
        this.dateFromFilter // will be null until set
        this.dateToFilter // will be null until set
        this.$scope // will give you the scope of the controller
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm really sorry, I should have posted my error message in the question above in the first place. I'll do that in a minute...

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using? also are you able to recreate your issue in a plunkr (or something similair)

Comment: `tsc` tells me that its version 1.8.7. Im tryining do do it in plunker currently, but it seems not to support TypeScript out-of-the-box. Wokring on it.. But: Did you also try to use the function as a filter? Because that is the point where it breaks for me?

Comment: Might be a silly one, in your html you have your controller defined like this - `<div ng-controller "MyController as ctrl">` make sure it is `<div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">` (your missing the =)

Comment: Yeah, thats just a typo in the above question. In my application, the '=' is not missing. Out of curiosity: Have you been using the function as filter as in the example HTML from above? Because: If i use the function *not* inside the filter, it is working just fine.